# JEST Not Supporting Optional Chaining Operator

Tags: lwc-jest

I am using the optional chaining operator in one of my LWC components -- running in VS Code with the canonical Salesforce setup.  All vanilla.

Here is the line of code and the error when I run a JEST test related to the component:

```
Details:

    C:\Users\Dave2\Documents\Visual Studio Code\TMS\force-app\main\default\lwc\stopDetail\stopDetail.js:1723
        let message = event?.detail?.message;
                            ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1258:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (force-app/main/default/lwc/loadDetail/loadDetail.html.compiled:12:1)
```

How do I change my config so JEST understands the optional chaining operator?  Thanks.

Adding package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tms",
  "version": "7.2.0",
  "description": "tms",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
    "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage",
    "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
    "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of jest do you have? A comment I found says that `^0.9.2 should work.

Comment: Thanks, sfdcfox.  Where exactly do I find that information and how do I upgrade if I need to?  My jest.config does not have much in it: const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    // add any custom configurations here
};

Comment: OK just found it in package.json and it is version 0.9.2.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't use jest yet, it's on my todo list when I get some time, so I can't really add an appropriate answer, but it intuitively feels like a versioning problem. Try upgrading node, sfdx, npm, etc (everything in your toolkit, basically) to the latest version. If everything is up to date, it should work.

Comment: OK thanks I will give that a try.

Comment: @DaveC Upgrade to *nodejs 14* version has solved the problem for us. Got the solution from here: https://githubmemory.com/repo/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/241

Comment: Thanks, wesaw!  That worked.